# Wordpress Widget went away

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, widget

Does anybody knows why this code is no more showing the Google Map?

It is on a Wordpress widget. It has worked before now.

```
<div class="Flexible-container clearfix">
    <div  class="textwidget">
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zP7FyRFSDjg4.ktg_BvCMvuxQ" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-widget','http://www.google.com']);">Versione ingrandita della mappa</a></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise if you put the map URL on a browser you can see the map regularly

Thanks, bye

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to do that now is to use the iframe approach, aka [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide).

With which you use:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

this to embed your maps onto your page.

Note that you need an API key and you can get it from the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Comment: Thanks Kaho. Maybe map disappeared because it needs API key now?

Comment: I think the way you did that is not supported anymore

Comment: More tests show to me that iframe has not been supported. In the past it was